# How many eyes Panchmukhi Mahadeva have: 11 or 15?

Tags: shiva

How many eyes Panchmukhi Mahadeva have:

11 = 5*2 and one third eye

or

15 = 5*3 (all heads have 3 eyes)

Ramcharitmanas mentions 15 eyes. What do other scriptures mention (preferably in Dhyana Shloka) about this?

Comment: Nityakarma Pujaprakash page 138 mentions 5 heads and 3 eyes in dhyanshloka..